# Plot with multiple graphs

Tags: r, plot

I would like to generate a plot like the following:

[image]

This is a plot which demonstrates "dialation" and "translation" of a function called Wavelet. The function here is not important, but just how I can generate a plot like this.

Can someone give me a hint which is the best way to do it? How can I get the six coordinate axes like in the plot? Should I start with `par(mfrow=c(3,3))`?

Until now I have managed this with the following code:

```
mo<-function(t,trans=0,omega=6,j=0){
  dial<-2*2^(j*.125)
  sqrt((1/dial))*pi^(-1/4)*exp(1i*omega*((t-trans)/dial))*exp(-((t-trans)/dial)^2/2)
}

par(mfrow=c(3,3))

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=-3)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=0)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=3)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)


#############

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=-3,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=0,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=3,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)


#############

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=-3,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=0,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)

plot(seq(-10,10,length=1000),Re(mo(seq(-10,10,length=1000),trans=3,j=6)),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="l")
abline(h=0,v=0)
```

[image]

But it is still not what I need

Comment: "I could probably do this myself, but would need too much time, which I do not have now" implies SO is a code writing service, which it is not.  You may want to rephrase that.

Comment: Check out the `fig` option in `par`.  It allows you to plot on some certain percentage of the region.  In this case, you'd probably want to use `mfrow = c(3, 3)` on the bottom 80% (give or take) of the plot region.

Comment: I would definitely have a look at `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` in `ggplot2`. These take care of a lot of the work with these kinds of multi-facet plots.

Comment: I have never used the package `ggplot2` so it woul cost too much time...

Comment: What's wrong with your results? If the margins are too wide, adjust `par(mar=c(...)`.

Comment: For example, the two arrows with "Ort b" ans "Skala a". Ant the coordinate axes should be like arrows like in the original plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `layout` to create a specific arrangement of plots, with extra panels for the long arrows on the left and top side

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1), oma=c(5,4,4,2))
m = matrix( c(0, 1, 1, 1,
              2, 3, 4, 5,
              2, 6, 7, 8, 
              2, 9, 10, 11),
        byrow=T, ncol=4)
l = layout(mat=m, widths=c(.1, .2, .2, .2), heights= c(.1, .2, .2, .2))

# check if the layout is as we expect
layout.show(l)

# add top arrow to panel 1
plot(1, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(0,1), type='n', axes=F, ann=F)
arrows(x0=1, x1=10, y0=0.5, y1=0.5)
mtext(side=3,'some text')
# add left arrow to panel 2
plot(1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(1,10), type='n', axes=F, ann=F)
arrows(y0=10, y1=1, x0=0.5, x1=0.5)
mtext(side=2,'some text')

# add plots to panels 3:11
for (i in 1:9){

    curve(sin(x), -2*pi, 2*pi, axes=F, ann=F)

    # get x and y extents of plot for drawing arrows
    ymax = par('usr')[4]
    ymin = par('usr')[3]
    xmax = par('usr')[2]
    xmin = par('usr')[1]
    arrows(x0=0, y0=ymin, x1=0, y1=ymax, length=0.1)
    arrows(x0=xmin, y0=0, x1=xmax, y1=0, length=0.1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Look good! Maybe you have a suggestion how to add text to the overall-arrows like in my original one?

Comment: Use `mtext`, added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
fmo<-function(t,trans=0,omega=6,j=0){
  dial<-2*2^(j*.125)
  sqrt((1/dial))*pi^(-1/4)*exp(1i*omega*((t-trans)/dial))*exp(-((t-trans)/dial)^2/2)
}

dat <- expand.grid(x=seq(-10,10, length = 200),
               trans = c(-3,0,3), 
               j = c(0, 6, 12))
dat$g <- rep(1:9, each = 200)
dat$y <- with(dat, Re(fmo(t=x,trans=trans,omega=6,j=j)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~g, ncol = 3)
```

[image: ggplot solution 1]

and work from here with some thematic formatting

```
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0)) +
  facet_wrap(~g, ncol = 3) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: solution 2]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It looks nice, but the problem is, taht in your version the plots look like they were separate, but this is not the impression I would like to make. The wavelets are aplied to the same time series, in "translated" and "dilated" versions, in order to generate a two-dimensional decomposition.

Comment: @RStudent Sorry, I can't figure out what you mean. Any link to a known solution? It seems to me that you need a mixed approach, with some art editing.