# How to add number of row and columns to the multiple plots

Tags: r

I would like to combine multiple plots in one plot using `mfrow` function.

Then, I would like to add the number of row and column to this plot.

For example,

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
plot(rnorm(10,1,3))
plot(rnorm(10,2,4))
plot(rnorm(10,3,3))
plot(rnorm(10,4,4))
plot(rnorm(10,5,2))
plot(rnorm(10,3,0.5))
```

I would like to have similar to this:[image: This photo]

Any help, please?

Comment: Cannot find anything like that in the documentation of par / layout / ggplot. Closest I can think of is including a plot title with the number, e.g. `plot(rnorm(10,1,3),main="1")`

Comment: @CIAndrews Thank you so much for your comment. I have about 13 plots combined in one plot with their own title. However, some of these plots are very similar and hence, I tried to make it is easy to refer to the individual plot.

Comment: Easiest: `ggplot::facet_grid`, tons of posts on SO. `base`R: [Plot with multiple graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213135/plot-with-multiple-graphs); [Title key on each panel of a plot generated with par(mfrow=c(x,y))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690175/title-key-on-each-panel-of-a-plot-generated-with-parmfrow-cx-y); [How to add annotations to a 28 multi-plot case in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818419/how-to-add-annotations-to-a-28-multi-plot-case-in-r). [A nice cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/how-big-is-your-graph.pdf)

Comment: One vote for `facet_grid`. Would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider `GGally` package. It draws pairwise scatter plot using `ggplot2`. I guess this is what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
(mu_sd <- # parameters
  tribble(
    ~m, ~s,
    #--/--/
    1, 3,
    2, 4,
    3, 3,
    4, 4,
    5, 2,
    3, .5
  ))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       m     s
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   3  
#> 2     2   4  
#> 3     3   3  
#> 4     4   4  
#> 5     5   2  
#> 6     3   0.5
```

Applying `rnorm` to this data frame, we can get another data frame to draw a plot

```
set.seed(10)
(rand_norm <-
  mu_sd %>% 
  apply(1, rnorm, n = 10) %>% # to each row
  as_tibble())
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  1.02   3.10 2.40   2.15  6.09 2.60 
#>  2  2.82   4.76 0.815  3.92  1.24 0.165
#>  3 -0.371  1.76 2.33   4.97  4.17 4.37 
#>  4  2.40   4.99 0.881  4.18  2.83 2.64 
#>  5  1.29   2.74 1.73   2.62  4.03 3.51 
#>  6  3.39   4.09 2.63   2.56  1.97 1.29 
#>  7 -0.208  1.05 2.31   4.36  5.23 2.10 
#>  8  2.64   3.80 2.13   2.24  1.70 1.03 
#>  9 -0.627  2.93 2.90   3.68  4.32 2.35 
#> 10  2.74   4.48 2.75   3.35  2.66 0.791
```

Here, each column came from each population.

You can now use `ggpairs()` in `GGally`.

```
GGally::ggpairs(rand_norm)
```

[image]

You can specify what to draw in each `upper`, `lower`, and `diag` side of the plot. This is the default result. In the lower part, you might see the result what you want.

If you are interested in the detail, then you can go to this link [GGally](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/#ggallyggpairs). However in this situation I think the default option is enough to solve the problem.